# I keep getting this boolean error when trying to publish my ASP.NET MVC app to Windows Azure using Web Deploy

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, microsoft-web-deploy

I keep getting this error when I try to publish my app to windows Azure using Web Deploy:

> Error 1  Expected "$(TransformWebConfigEnabled)" to evaluate to a
>   boolean instead of "0", in condition "@(WebConfigsToTransform)!='' And
>   $(TransformWebConfigEnabled) And
>   !$(UseParameterizeToTransformWebConfig)"

I am trying to add the following elements to my .**csproj** file settings (in the `PropertyGroup` element) so that I don't get the parameterized **web.config** file:

```
<TransformWebConfigEnabled>False</TransformWebConfigEnabled>
  <AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
    False
  </AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
```

When I add these elements to the project file, I get the blue line under the `TransformWebConfigEnabled` element as if something is wrong and Visual Studio states that its an invalid child element for the `PropertyGroup` element. Now, even when I remove these elements from the project file, it still gives me the error message above.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Another thing, when I build I get no errors, when I debug I get no errors and the app runs perfectly on my local machine when I debug (via the browser). This only happens when I try to publish to Azure using Web Deploy (I tried both Release and Debug options for Web Deploy).

Comment: Did you happen to open this project in MonoDevelop or Xamarin Studio?

Comment: No, I don't use either of those.  I only use Visual Studio.

Comment: Ok, I had the exact same error few days ago and it was caused by Xamarin adding extra 'Import' lines to my project file, so I created a new project and looked at what was required and deleted the extra ones. That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Did the Import lines look like this:

<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
      
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
      
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />

Comment: Yes, they were right at the bottom of the file. I had 1 duplicated and 1 extra, so i removed the 2.

Comment: I have no dupes or extras for the Import Project elements.